# Neural network help on game of continuous snake

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to implement an AI for a game of 'continuous snake'. It's very different from a normal snake game, at least as far as the AI is concerned. Basically, the snake drives a bit like a car and the first one of the 2 players to crash into his trail or the other's trail loses the game. Also the screen wraps around its borders.

You can understand it better if you look at a video of my current progress: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9qU-r4COQ8

It's not too bad, but it still can't beat me (I'm yellow).
A winning AI would ideally need to exhibit these behaviors:

1. Avoid walls
2. Notice occasions when it can 'cut me short' (when next to me a bit ahead).
3. Avoid getting 'cut short'.
4. Have an idea of the topology of the current 2d space to try to enclose me in a smaller space / safeguard himself a bigger space.

My current approach uses the NEAT algorithm (http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html).
It's a genetic algorithm that evolves neural networks over generations. It learned how to do 1,2 and 3 to some extent (but not great) but has no idea about 4.

For the inputs, I'm using:

- the opponent angle relative to us
- the opponent distance to us
- the opponent heading relative to us
- smart rays that probe in some directions with some amount of tree search (see video)

I'm a bit stuck now though and would like to know:

- What's the class of algorithms I should look into ? Recurrent / RealTime / Continous / Unsupervised Neural networks, ... An explanation about these and how they would apply to my problem would be great.
- Any specific algorithms I should research ?
- What other sets of inputs could I use ? A human player gets to see all the pixels in the game which is a lot more information than my simple set of inputs. But I don't think feeding the 200x200 pixels in my example to my NN would work at all. Maybe if I discretize them and make them relative to the AI position/heading...sounds tricky.

I'm happy to make my code available if someone wants to see it (C#).

Thanks!

Comment: If this is giving you decent results I would try to add more features as inputs to the Neural Network. You could feed it the X,Y co-ordinates of itself and the opponent. You can also calculate the distance the opponent is travelling and have that as a feature. I am interested in how you define your fitness function and how you determine it to evolve the agent.

Comment: I already give the relative position/heading of the opponent, that's all it needs as the screen wraps around itself I think. Yeah I need to get a bit more creative with the inputs... The fitness function is very simple - I play different versions of the AI against themselves, the winner gets 10 fitness and the loser 1. I did some tweaking there to give even more points if the winner wins 'quickly'. The 5% best AIs get to 'reproduce' themselves and mix their genes to create a smarter NN.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with different number of hidden layers or even allowing the structure of the neural network to evolve (assuming you are only evolving the weights). You must also think about the constraints of the optimization. For example I am evolving racing AI with evolutionary Neural Network and the best agent yet uses the walls of the track in some places to help him get better turn, because I am not penalizing for that. So if you want the AI to learn specific behavior you need to make sure the fitness function rewards for that kind of a behavior.

Comment: I'm wondering vlad, in the video I see a neural network with no hidden layers. I also see that you're rewarding 'winning', but what about rewarding 'alive time'. You should experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that your learning algorithm doesn't have enough information (unless you are using the recurrency feature). Basically, each frame you're asking it to navigate a maze by a few distance sensors - impossible.

What singhV said before is true - for good results, the input for the learning algorithm has to be the image (as well as your own head position and angle). You can lower the resolution a bit and convert to monochrome for efficiency.

As for your questions:
* Recurrent networks are networks that can remember previous state, and use it like "memory" basically. Its not what you need for this task (unless you really want to keep the inputs as they are, but then the snake would have to learn "remembering" all it saw - it would be pretty impressive but too hard)
* Unsupervised: it means that there are no "examples" to learn from, instead learning by positive / negative feedback (losing = bad). Your network is unsupervised.
* Real Time / Continuous - no idea, i didnt find anything except some 2007 microsoft research: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/continuous-neural-networks/

By the way, NEAT is pretty neat, I'm glad I ran into this!

Answer (score 0):

I cant post comments yet so I will post here my suggestion, but I dont expect it to be a full answer to your question, just ideas for you to build on.

1) try to input the available area for your "snake" to move. This might not be easy to do and you will have to take some assumptions. For example: assume that the opponent takes the route that Minimizes your area, or simpler that the opponent maintains the same direction.

2) try to input an aggressive strategy, meaning compute the opponent available area. the algorithm could try to maximize your area while minimizing the opponents area.

3) finally, try something different from ANNs. If you formulate your problem as a minimization/maximization task you could use a lot of methods to solve it.

Cool stuff by the way!

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you want good results use **deep convolutional q-learning** which takes the image as input. For further improvement you can feed in stack of three to four consecutive images which will help lot in determing a direction.I don't think you need to use lstm for this problem **stacking multiple frames will do fine**. For further improvement you can convert the same code into duelling network.

And if you prefer **fast results** and **less computation** you can use **augmented random search** but if not trained with care it may get into local maxima.

Comment: Can I understand did I miss anything in my answer. I think it will solve your issue.